# React Input Range updating state slowly

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, input, range

I'm trying to use an html  element with the `type="range"` to make a range slider that will update a state value as I slide it back and forth. It works smoothly if I simply console.log `e.target.value` inside of `onInputChange()` without setting the state, but if I try to setState with the e.target.value, it lags so much that it's unusable. I've also tried setting the `value={this.state.rangeValue}` inside , with no success. Here is an example of the relevant code:

```
export default class App extends Component {
   constructor() {
   super();
   this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);

   this.state = {
     rangeValue: 50
   }
 }

onInputChange(e) {
   this.setState({ rangeValue: e.target.value});
}

render() {
   var {rangeValue} = this.state;

  // this logs unbearably slow and I want to be able to pass this value 
  // to a child component as a prop as it updates
  console.log(rangeValue)

  return (
     <div className="map-controls">
        <input type="range" onChange={this.onInputChange}></input>
        <ExampleComponent rangeValue={this.state.rangeValue} />
     </div>

  );
 }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is so slow? Maybe the ExampleComponent is the bottleneck. I tested your example with a simple div for the output and there were no performance issues..

Comment: @webdeb The part that seems slow is setting the state and re-rendering the component. Like I mentioned, if I just `console.log(e.target.value)` within `onInputChange` then it logs the values properly and responsively as I slide the slider around. However, if I use setState like my code example, then `console.log(this.state.rangeValue)` inside the render method, the values update in a really janky way and sometimes freezes up as I slide the slider around. I thought that maybe because it forces the component to re-render every time I slide the slider. This happens even without ExampleComponent

Comment: yes `setState` forces to re-render the component, but as I said I tested it on a fresh react-app and it was fine.. what is the `ExampleComponent` doing?

Comment: @webdeb Nope, totally working now. Literally didn't change a thing, but since I had time between work I tested it again and it just works now. Very odd since I spent an hour messing with it just yesterday with no success. --\_(ツ)_/

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if my package could help you out?

https://github.com/bluebill1049/react-smooth-range-input

```
import react from 'react';
import Slider from 'react-smooth-range-input';

export default () => <Slider value={1} min={1} max={30} onChange={/** you can put your callback here */} />;
```

Answer (score 0):

@user3737841 It seems that you are updating the state of the component on `onInputChange()` handler. On each step value change of the input range slider, the setState is called and re-render happens. This is to be very costly to re-render on each input change.

If you avoid updating the state, you'll probably save some renders and your performance will improve.

You can also use `defaultValue` instead of `value`. Then the `<input>` is considered as `uncontrolled` and any user interactions are immediately reflected by element itself without invoking render function of your component.

Just replace `value={this.state.rangeValue}` with `defaultValue={this.state.rangeValue}`. Pass the slider `value` as `prop` to the `<ExampleComponent />` component regrdless of  component `state`.